# Cancel Order API Error - Validation Failed For The Field Change Reason

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm using the following code to cancel a sales order header using `API OE_ORDER_PUB`

But always returned `Validation failed for the field - Change Reason`

```
DECLARE
    --variable declare
BEGIN
    -- Setting the Enviroment --

    FOR I
        IN (SELECT oh.header_id     order_header_id
              FROM oe_order_headers_all oh
             WHERE oh.order_number IN (12301000013) AND oh.org_id = v_org_id)
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            -- CANCEL HEADER --
            v_header_rec.cancelled_flag := 'Y';
            v_header_rec.change_reason := 'Not Provided';

            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Starting cancel of API');

            -- CALLING THE API TO CANCEL AN ORDER --

            OE_ORDER_PUB.PROCESS_ORDER (
                x_header_rec               => v_header_rec_out
                --... using the parameter
                );
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('error in block. reason is :' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

How could i find the requirement rules for change reason field in `OE_ORDER_HEADERS` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much info here to work with but here is what you could try

1. Check if there are validations on the page. The most probably cause of this error is that there is a page item with the label "Cancel Reason" that has a validation on it. That validation is failing which raises this validation error
2. Check if the procedure `OE_ORDER_PUB.PROCESS_ORDER` has any code to verify if the order can be cancelled.

Also, `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line`  cannot be used in apex pl/sql code. DBMS_OUTPUT prints message to the buffer of the client (sqlplus/sqldeveloper/apex sql workshop). In apex those calls will not do anything but they should be removed from the code since they could cause buffer overflows.

To properly instrument your code, use [APEX_DEBUG](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aeapi/APEX_DEBUG.html#GUID-8E80E46E-CCEF-4CCC-8D00-8EC3A5C36FDE) to add comments that can be seen in debug mode and [APEX_ERROR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aeapi/APEX_ERROR.html#GUID-F9353D6E-85FB-48EE-B493-3A0C0F596436) for handling errors.

For your code that would be something like

```
DECLARE
    --variable declare
BEGIN
    -- Setting the Enviroment --

    FOR I
        IN (SELECT oh.header_id     order_header_id
              FROM oe_order_headers_all oh
             WHERE oh.order_number IN (12301000013) AND oh.org_id = v_org_id)
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            -- CANCEL HEADER --
            v_header_rec.cancelled_flag := 'Y';
            v_header_rec.change_reason := 'Not Provided';

            apex_debug.info('Starting cancel of API');

            -- CALLING THE API TO CANCEL AN ORDER --

            OE_ORDER_PUB.PROCESS_ORDER (
                x_header_rec               => v_header_rec_out
                --... using the parameter
                );
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
     apex_error.add_error (
       p_message          => 'error in block. reason is :' || SQLERRM,
       p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification );
END;
```